# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at prac.js:3

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var hi = document.querySelector("h1");
hi.style.color = "red";
```

---

This 2 line code of giving a color to h1 using DOM is giving ERROR

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null  at prac.js:3

when writing in separate javascript file whereas same 2 lines works fine in console and produces the desired effect.

---

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Experiments</title>
<script src = "prac.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hey there!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo of the issue:

```js
var hi = document.querySelector("h1");
hi.style.color = "red";
```

Comment: Try to add `<script src="prac.js"></script>` inside `<body>` at bottom once.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032997/how-to-get-the-value-of-h1-tag-using-js

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not clear how you are using the JavaScript, so identifying the actual issues is difficult. 

However, let us assume you are using JavaScript inside the same file HTML only, then the code you wrote is working fine, you can check below code snippet.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Experiments</title>
        <script src = "prac.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Hey there!</h1>
       <script>
          var hi = document.querySelector("h1");
          hi.style.color = "red";
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Since mostly we are manipulating the `DOM` using JavaScript, this is a good practice to have JavaScript load from another file(or if you are using Javascript on the same page)at the bottom of your **HTML** content, just before the `</body>` tag, as till then most HTML content would have loaded to be used by the DOM.

If your JavaScript code is inside **parc.js** file, then you need to add that file just above the `</body>` tag, as shown in the below code.

Your **HTML** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Experiments</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hey there!</h1>
      <script src = "prac.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Your **JavaScript** code

```
 var hi = document.querySelector("h1");
 hi.style.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your script runs before `DOM` renders. As Palash suggested, put your script tag at the end of the body tag.